# Using jQuery to clean up HTML code?

Tags: jquery, html

Using jQuery, does anyone know how I can clean this markup:

```
<span style="font-size:19px">
  <span style="font-size:20px">
    <span style="font-size:21px">
      Something
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

...and transform it into this:

```
<span style="font-size:21px">
  Something
</span>
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated. Or if anyone knows of any libraries that can remove useless tags from HTML, that would be great too.

---

UPDATE

The above code is just an example. There could be 20 wrapped spans for example...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) all the span tags, that would leave only the inner span tag.

```
$('span').unwrap();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v3UaV/)

Comment: Won't this remove all spans?

Comment: @Andrew - nope, the inner tag won't be removed

Comment: @Andrew - Take a look at the Fiddle - only the two outer spans are removed :)

Comment: @Andrew: the `span`s will be unwrapped, not the contents of the `span`s (albeit should there be any sibling nodes to the innermost `span` that could be problematic ([but *isn't*](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/v3UaV/1/)).

Comment: @Andrew you have a live demo, and still you come up with this question.

Comment: This is a good solution and answers my question - I'll mark as the accepted. However, in your example, what about it the inner-most span didn't have a color set. The color set by the parent span would be lost...

Comment: @Andrew - Indeed, that's the point of unwrapping, one can't expect styles on elements that are removed to persist on the children left behind

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
$('span').each(function() {
    if($(this).prop('tagName') == $(this).children(":first").prop('tagName')) {
       $(this).children(":first").unwrap();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not a jQuery solution, but I don't know if you need it to live process your HTML. Otherwise you could use this online tool: http://www.dirtymarkup.com/ it will transform your code:

```
<span style="font-size:19px">
  <span style="font-size:20px">
    <span style="font-size:21px">
      Something
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

into:

```
<span style="font-size: 19px">Something</span>
```