# Clean up HTML with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Using jQuery, how can I turn this:

```
<span style="font-size:19px">
    <span style="font-size:20px; color:#ff0000">
        <span style="font-size:21px;">
            Something
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

...into this:

```
<span style="font-size:21px; color:#ff0000">
  Something
</span>
```

Note the useless spans are removed BUT the color is maintained.

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617567/using-jquery-to-clean-up-html-code), I asked how to remove useless SPANs from a string and the result was to use:

```
$('span').unwrap();
```

This works great BUT in the above example, it doesn't take into account the color.

Can anyone think of an effective to handle this?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: If the HTML needs to be cleaned up, why not just clean up the HTML?

Comment: @Jason P = I'm building a wysiwyg and users can style the markup... It's working great but I'm ending up with tons of nested spans. I'd like to run a cleaning function after the user is finished...

Comment: @Tim - yes, exactly. Do you know of a library or anthing that can do this?

Comment: @Andrew Tim means, why in first place not set a clean HTML?

Comment: @Wolff - I'm trying to and understanding how to solve the above is one of the steps I need to tackle...

Comment: Have you tried using `attr("style")`?

Comment: I think you'll have a much easier time with clean HTML in the first place than scripting a fix...this kind of thing is notoriously difficult to get right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could list all the properties you want this way can work.

If you have a common container you can do:

```
var $container = $('.container-for-useless-spans');

// This is an array of the properties to grab...
var properties_to_get = ['color', 'font-size'];

// Grab the CSS properties from the deepest span since it'll have all the parents styling...
var styles_to_copy = $container.find('span:last').css(properties_to_get);

// Just grab the text from the container and apply the styles that were on the deepest span..
$container.html($container.text()).css(styles_to_copy);


<div class="container-for-useless-spans">
  <span style="font-size:19px">
    <span style="font-size:20px; color:#ff0000">
        <span style="font-size:21px;">
            Something
        </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Here is a quick demo: http://jsbin.com/IneXasOL/1/edit?html,js,output

I personally would just clean up the HTML, though. This is silly, especially considering how trivial it is for the browser to handle it as it is.

Answer (score 2):

In case that you want to preserve the inherited `color` property, one option is using `css` method, for preventing conflicts/better performance, you can filter the elements that has no descendant span elements.

```
$('span').css('color', function() {
   return $(this).css('color');
}).unwrap();
```

For filtering `span`s that have no descendant `span` elements you can use `.filter()` method. (I haven't tested the performance of it versus the previous snippet):

```
$('span').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).find('span').length;
}).css('color', function() {
    return $(this).css('color');
}).end()
  .unwrap();
```

Comment: I withdraw my objection, apparently $.css wraps `getComputedStyle`. My mistake.

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that this is *horifically* inefficient. It'd be far better if OP's original HTML were tidy...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes, it's not efficient. And client-side JavaScript shouldn't be used for _cleaning_ the markup at first place.

Comment: Why not grab the deepest span and get the styles from that since all the parent's styles are inherited? Trying to understand if there's something wrong with the way I approached my answer.

Comment: @BillCriswell Are you referring to the `:last` selector? It returns the last element from the collection, it won't work for several nested span elements. That's why I had used the `.filter()` method.

Comment: I think it does work for the nested elements. `$('span:last')` on `<span><span><span class="foo">foo</span></span></span>` returns `span.foo`.

Comment: @BillCriswell I meant for the several _nested span elements_, in case that your snippet is considered one of them. Here the `color` property of the last `span` element is applied to other survived `span` s.

Comment: Ah, I see! I would need to do like `span:last` on everything `.container > span` returns.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to *try* and implement a multi-purpose, pure-JS solution. This will apply to all elements that have no siblings (ie. wrappers of wrappers), however note that in some cases this WILL break your site's layout. I will go into detail on this after the code. Also note that I do NOT encourage use of this code. This is more an exercise of my ability to do something.

```
(function() {
  var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*"), l = all.length, i, k;
  for( i=l-1; i>=0; i--) { // by going backwards, children are processed before parents
    if( !all[i].parentNode || all[i].parentNode.children.length != 1) continue;
    // element is only child, apply its styles to parent node and transfer children
    for( k in all[i].style) {
      if( all[i].style.hasOwnProperty(k) && all[i].style[k]
                                            && typeof all[i].style[k] == "string") {
        all[i].parentNode.style[k] = all[i].style[k];
      }
    }
    while(all[i].firstChild) all[i].parentNode.appendChild(all[i].firstChild);
    // finally, remove current node
    all[i].parentNode.removeChild(all[i]);
  }
})();
```

All being well, this should produce the desired effect on the entire document.

I REPEAT: THIS IS BAD! You should be producing tidy HTML, and shouldn't even be using the inline `style` attribute anyway. Separate content and format, or something like that, I dunno. I use the `style` attribute and I don't care...

Anyways, this WILL break pages in some circumstances. For example, assume you have a list with a single item:

```
<ul><li>Derp</li></ul>
```

The code above will change it to:

```
<ul>Derp</ul>
```

Which is, for obvious reasons, invalid. This could maybe be fixed with an additional check, like so:

```
if( !all[i].pare ... || all[i].nodeName != all[i].parentNode.nodeName) continue;
```

***ONE MORE TIME***: This is NOT code you should be using for anything other than as an exercise!

Comment: Wow - I'm evaluating this, I'll be back

Comment: This looks good too but I have to give it to @Bill Criswell cause he answered first and provide a jQuery solution

Answer (score 0):

This function should do it:

```
var font, color;

$(span).each(function () {
   if ($(this).css('font-size')) { font = $(this).css('font-size');}
   if ($(this).css('color')) { font = $(this).css('color');}
});

$(span).unwrap().addCss({'font-size' : font, 'color' : color)});
```

Basically just looping through all the spans (you can always be more specific with locking down the section of spans you want to loop through) and setting the font and color with the latest found value.  At the end you unwrap all the spans and set the font-size and color to the values that would have last been encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered implementing a 3rd party library to clean up the entirety of your WYSIWYG editor?  Check out HTML Purifier http://htmlpurifier.org/

Not only will this clean up your HTML but it will also be a nice way to clean up other potential issues like XSS and injection within your posted form.